# Is there no way to run asynchronous work with WorkManager?

Tags: android-workmanager

At this point I'm struggling to use `WorkManager` for anything and there must be something I'm missing. It seems everything must be done in the `onWork()` method and there are no callbacks or options to end the work later on. So if I want to determine the device position I seemingly cant wait for the `GoogleApi` client to return a lat/long before ending the `WorkManager` work since I cant see a way to wait for callbacks.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

Most `GoogleApi`s returns `Task` types and you call await on them to block before you can return. If the API you happen to use uses callbacks then you can use a `CountDownLatch` for now. We are working on adding support for `NonBlockingWorker`s.

Comment: Awesome to hear that WorkManager get support for this soon. I'll probably wait until then before I start using it but I'll look into using something like a CountDownLatch. Thanks.